# Does String object in Java store characters in a char array?

Tags: java, java-6

I am solving an assignment where I should  not  use arrays or collections to sort Integers. I am doing it with strings. I want to know whether strings in java are stored as character array.

Comment: Strings are an abstraction. Why does their internal operation matter? This sounds like [an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242)

Comment: Maybe look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java)?

Comment: can you be more clear **about the data storage** ? is ONLY arrays banned or u can use any subclass of java.util.Collections

Comment: Yeah, no collections should be used.

Comment: can you update your post with details like **how many** integers are excepted ? **fixed** ??

Comment: ints [0-9] , length upto 10 million

Comment: please provide some detail or specific problem..

Comment: Well , My question is about String implementation thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LinkedList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList) where implementation is not backed by an array.

Yes [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) does use char array behind the scene

Comment: thanks SMA . I wanted to just know whether string object stores characters in char array. I can take it from here. thank you very much

Comment: I suggest seeing my answer; this is taking you down the wrong path.

Comment: But really, this all depends on the stipulations of your professor, and what THEY define as allowable.

Answer (score -1):

While some are saying to check the Java source, I'll save you some time.

I can guarantee that even starting the JVM uses a collection in some way. That is how fundamental they are to programming. So I'm assuming your assignment takes that into account. Therefore, in this case, I would say for these, your professor means to not explicitly use a collection or array. **Avoiding behind the scenes collections is literally impossible.**

Don't believe me? Take a look at this code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    // looks like an array to me ^
}
```

Do note that the `String` class in Java has a `toCharArray()` method, so avoid this.

Comment: I truely agree with you. Its a test to see how 'out of box' I can think or how I can come up with an alternative or how I can face challenges. In real projects collections are indispensable.